# How to access a constructor in a staticmethod in python?

Tags: python, flask, rabbitmq, pika

I am trying to access a class instance inside a `staticmethod` but I'm having difficulties in doing that. This is my class:

```
class Worker:
    def __init__(self, ch, method, properties, body):
        self.ch = ch
        self.method = method
        self.properties = properties
        self.body = body

    @staticmethod
    def receive_payload_and_validate_schema(body):
        # some logic

        return body

    @staticmethod
    def some_func(id_info, partner_params):
        id_response = {}
        # some logic
        self.ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=self.method.delivery_tag) # This is where the problem is

        return id_response

    @staticmethod
    def another_func(body):
        id_info = {} # assume it contains keys and values
        partner_params = {} # assume it contains keys and values
        # some logic
        return Worker.some_func(id_info, partner_params)
```

How can I use this expression, `self.ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=self.method.delivery_tag)`, inside the `some_func` staticmethod?

Answer (score 1):

By definition, static methods are not associated with an instance of the class. Either the `some_func` should not be static, or `ch` should also be static.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a static method.  In your code, you are reference `self`, which is never passed to a static method.

```
self.ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=self.method.delivery_tag)
```

In Python OOP, when a standard method is called, the object that calls the method is passed as the first argument.  Traditionally this is called `self`.  In the line above, you are using `self`, but it has no reference.